# Some of my posts were deleted not by my own? How can I check those and get one backup

Tags: discussion

Few of my questions seems to be deleted? and I gained 2 reputations(which notify me), Can I find them? Some of them have revision history, though they are not good questions by now, however, in the future I'll edit them!

And I need them, and I want to save them an html as backup...
However late to do that, since I do not know they would be deleted...

But now seems I cannot find them.

[image]

Comment: The rules have changed now that every user should be able to see their own question if they have a link to it (regardless of their rep). [Here's a list](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=VAi9eQsb) of all your deleted questions... perhaps you should try aiming better before shooting? ;)

Comment: @rm-rf got it, some were deleted by `Community Moderator ♦`.

Comment: @rm-rf can you maybe also give me a link to my most recent deleted question? It was tagged probability and the title was categorical distribution. Silly of me not to keep a link :(

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom Sure, here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43293 In future, you might be able to find your recently deleted questions here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/4330 (you can get to that page from the "questions" tab on your profile).

Comment: @rm-rf ah, ok thank you, also for the for tip!

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow [meta thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2645/181998) about this feature.

You can find a link to your **deleted recent questions** on your profile, at the bottom of your **Questions** page:

[image]